# Calling a variable from another function in go

Tags: go

I know that variables are pass by value in go. However, I want to call a variable that in inside a func outside this function. Let me give you an example:

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
)

func Smile(){
  A := 5
}

func main() {

   fmt.Println(A)

}
```

This gives me undefine A.

what is the best way to pass A ? Should I use a pointer? How do I do that?

Comment: Have you gone through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org)?

Comment: You don't call variables at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to print the value of the `A` variable declared in the `Smile()` function from `main()`.

And the main reason for that is that the variable `A` only exists if code execution enters the `Smile()` function, more precisely reaches the `A` variable declaration. In your example this never happens.

And even if in some other example this happens (e.g. `Smile()` is called), an application may have multiple goroutines, and multiple of them may be executing `Smile()` at the same time, resulting in the app having multiple `A` variables, independent from each other. In this situation, *which* would `A` in `main()` refer to?

[Go is lexically scoped using blocks.](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) This means the variable `A` declared inside `Smile()` is only accessible from `Smile()`, the `main()` function cannot refer to it. If you need such "sharing", you must define `A` outside of `Smile()`. If both `Smile()` and `main()` needs to access it, you have to make it either a global variable, or you have to pass it to the functions that need it.

Making it a global variable, this is how it could look like:

```
var a int

func smile() {
    a = 5
    fmt.Println("a in smile():", a)
}

func main() {
    smile()
    fmt.Println("a in main():", a)
}
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4MhN-Z3ersh)):

```
a in smile(): 5
a in main(): 5
```

Declaring it local in `main()` and passing it to `smile()`, this is how it could look like:

```
func smile(a int) {
    fmt.Println("a in smile():", a)
}

func main() {
    a := 5
    fmt.Println("a in main():", a)
    smile(a)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZXbwbKVDXRJ)):

```
a in main(): 5
a in smile(): 5
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason I am asking this question is because I want to define variables from an API in a function and pass those variables to other functions. You answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is, https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/pointer

> Pointers

Ex:

```
func getCar() {
   car := Vehicles.Car{}
   setModel(&car)
   // model ("BMW") will be available here
}

func setModel(car *Vehicles.Car) {
   car.Model = "BMW"
}
```